# How to achieve a layout with 3 columns and a footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I am trying to build this footer with bootstrap 3.3. The footer looks like this:

Text Left - Social Icons - Text Right

Here is what I tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/bsumgcpk/1/

```
            <div class="container black">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 white"><p> COPYRIGHT © 2014</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 white text-center"> 


                    <img src="icon-g-.png" alt="google+">
                        <img src="icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter">
                        <img src="icon-fb.png" alt="facebook">

            </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 right"><p> right text</p></div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Your  bootly non function (application error). show your code in another way

Comment: oops, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/bsumgcpk/1/

Comment: The code in jsfiddle is not the same you added to the question. But anyway what's you need?

Comment: The footer is broken on mobile. Looks fine on the desktop/tablet version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put the columns inside `row` div.
Bootstrap has 12 column grid system, so the sum of your columns should be `12`.
Thats why i used `3` columns of size `4`.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wazaaaap/bsumgcpk/3/).

```css
p {
    color: white;
}
.black {
    background: #000;
}
.right {
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.kissingerassoc.com/~order-portal/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container black">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 white">
            <p>COPYRIGHT © BITPHONE.ES 2014</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 white text-center">
            <img src="https://bitphone.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/icon-g-.png" alt="google+" />
            <img src="https://bitphone.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
            <img src="https://bitphone.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/icon-fb.png" alt="facebook" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 right">
            <p>right text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```